# Regex for Telugu String in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex

I am able to fetch the following Telugu string from the OCR results. I need to apply regular expressions for that string. Could anyone please help to how to fetch Gender, Name, Address

```
customStr = "డివిజన్‌: షాద్‌ నగర్‌\n(గ్రామం: వెలిజర్ల -1\n\n \n  \n \n\n \n\n \n\n||\n\n(|\n\n|||\n\n|||\n\nఖాతానెం.: 783\n\n  \n\n' 1. పట్టాదారు పేరు ఇంటిపేరుతో : చతుర్వేదుల భార్గవి\n., 2. తండ్రి / భర్తపేరు : శ్రీధర కేదార్‌ నాథ్‌\n\n౩. స్త్రీ / పురుషుడు : Female\n, 4. చిరునామా : వెలిజర్ల -1\n5. కులము : General\n6. ఆధార్‌ సంఖ్య : XXXXXXXX8381\n\n7. పట్టాదారు సంతకం ఎడమ /కుడి చేతి వేలిముద్ర\n\nతహశీల్దార్‌ సంత!\n\n \n\nith CamScanner"
```

I am using the following source code but no result.

```
String[] lines = customStr.split("\\r?\\n", -1);

        for(String line : lines) {



                if (customStr.contains("స్త్రీ / పురుషుడు")){
                    text4.setText(line);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.printf("ok");
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regex with Pattern and Matcher to fetch Gender, Name and Address.
Refer the below example:

```
    Pattern genderPattern = Pattern.compile("౩. స్త్రీ / పురుషుడు : (.*?)\n,");
    Pattern addressPattern = Pattern.compile("4. చిరునామా : (.*?)\n5.");
    Pattern namePattern  = Pattern.compile("1. పట్టాదారు పేరు ఇంటిపేరుతో : (.*?)\n.,");
    Matcher m;
    m=genderPattern.matcher(customStr);
    if(m.find())
        gender = m.group(1));
    m=addressPattern.matcher(customStr);
    if(m.find())
        address = m.group(1));
    m=namePattern.matcher(customStr);
    if(m.find())
        name = m.group(1));
```